# iTunes Connect New Version

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I am using Xcode 7.2. My app has successfully been validated and uploaded to the app store. I am up to date on all contracts that need to be accepted. However, when I go to "My Apps" > (click on my app) > "+ Version or Platform" > then 2 options show: iOS and tvOS. I click on iOS (my app is an iOS app) and nothing happens.

I have tried clicking the iOS option multiple times on multiple browsers and have even restarted my computer.

Is there something I am missing as to why this could happen? I have never run into this issue before and would greatly appreciate any advice!

Comment: Did you try another browser?

Comment: @injuanj yeah I tried Chrome and Safari and tried on a different computer as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a temporary IT issue as of June 29, 2016. According to Apple's customer service, the issue is being handled right now and "will be fixed shortly."

Comment: "shortly" must be loosely defined over there. You still having the issue? I still am

Comment: @slowsword It's definitely loosely defined. I called in just now and they said they are still working on the issue

Answer (score 0):

The same exact thing just happened to me. The only thing that fixed it was to have another user on the account create the new Version.

Edit:

I've figured out a simple fix that involves editing some HTML. Using the dev tools in safari or any browser, right click iOS/TVOS after clicking "Version or Platform" and click "inspect element" remove all the elements from the "li" tag aside from the one highlighted in the screenshot. Then remove the "ng-hide" from class. After that click on iOS  [image: Screenshot with change highlighted.]

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'll have to try that. After another user added the version were you able to add new versions later?

Comment: Im having same issue. Apple said it's a known issue.... curious to how many other accounts are affected. I tried creating a new admin account, did not work for me...

Comment: @slowsword Yeah I just spoke with Apple and they told me the same thing that is an IT issue and it's being handled. I created a new admin account and it did not work for me either.

Comment: Take a look at my edit. I found a wonky solution, but it works.